# How to parent an object to multiple bones?

Tags: rigging, parent, bone.constraints

So, I'm trying to rig a dragon with four fins lining his head and jaw. I need them to deform in a way that is believable, so at first I tried weight painting them between the head and jaw, but when I moved the jaw, they would shrink. So I realized I had to assign each fin to a bone, but I'm having trouble getting the bones to move properly.  When the dragon is in his default rest pose, the fin bones move properly when reacting to the jaw, but when I tilt the head, they move completely out of position. This is because the fin bones are parented to the head, and have a "Child of" constraint attached to the jaw. So when I move the head, it detects the movement of the jaw as well and the parent output of the head doubles up because of it. What I'm wondering is how I can make local deformations of the jaw affect the fin bones, but have transformations of the jaw caused by it's parent to the head bone not affect the fin bones. (Or if there's a different method to produce the desired result.)

[image: Default pose]

[image: Desired result for head rotation]

[image: undesired result of head rotation]

Comment: Maybe parent both fin bones and jaw bone to the head bone, then on top of that, add a child constraint (at like 40-50% power) to the fin bones so they are also moved by the jaw bone. It's kinda logical to what literally would be the case if the creature were real (i.e. head is moving everything, jaw is attached to it, and fins are also attached to the head AND also being affected by jaw movement)

Comment: @BuzzKirill That would create the same problem I have right now, only toned down. Like I explained the child of constraint is basically causing the head to effect the fin bones at like 200%. If I set the child of constraint to 40-50% power, the head would move the fin bones at 140-150%.

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry. I just tried a different setup using a Copy rotation constraint and it seems to do the job. 1) parent both fin and jaw to the head 2) add a Copy rotation constraint to the fin, with jaw as parent. 3) axis: the axis that the jaw rotates in (must be the same for fin, make sure to check the "roll" parameter for these bones. E.g. R, X, X should rotate both bones in a similar way ). Target and owner: local space. Influence: depends, set 0.5 as a start then tweak accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a use case of the Armature bone constraint, where the four fin bones get parented to head and jaw with weightings.

In order to work fine, jaw has to be child of the head, while fin bones are parented to nothing (they get parented via the armature constraints).
Check the "Preserve Volume" option to avoid shrinking, and trim weights differently fron one fin bone to another. When satisfied, push the "Normalize Weights" button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @josh_sanfecili That's perfect! Thank you so much!!